# Add foreign key in the auth user model

Tags: django

I'm new in Django and I'm trying to add a foreign key in the auth user model. I have different users, and each user has an unique university, but an university can have many users. I'm using django 1.6.

I found a lot of information about using User model as a foreign key, but almost nothing about adding a foreign key to the User model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, please read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

> There are two ways to extend the default User model without
>   substituting your own model. If the changes you need are purely
>   behavioral, and don’t require any change to what is stored in the
>   database, you can create a proxy model based on User. This allows for
>   any of the features offered by proxy models including default
>   ordering, custom managers, or custom model methods.
>
> If you wish to store information related to User, you can use a
>   one-to-one relationship to a model containing the fields for
>   additional information. This one-to-one model is often called a
>   profile model, as it might store non-auth related information about a
>   site user.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I made a UserProfile model with an onetoone relationships to user model.